# Unable to execute AutoCompleteTextView using Volley response in Android

Tags: java, android, autocomplete, adapter

I have been trying to implement AutoComplete feature on one of the applications I have been working on. 
The server sends back json response. I tried parsing it with Volley. It works but I have been unsuccessful in integrating the response with the autocompletetextview.

MainActivity.java

```
        user_input = findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView1);
        ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.select_dialog_item, mylist);

        String symbol_auto = String.valueOf(user_input.getText());


        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        //results = findViewById(R.id.jsonData);
        mylist.add("india");
        mylist.add("iran");
        JsonArrayRequest arrayreq = new JsonArrayRequest(company_auto+symbol_auto,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {

                    // Takes the response from the JSON request
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonobj = response.getJSONObject(0);
                            data = jsonobj.getString("Name");
                            mylist.add(data);
                            Log.i("here", data);
                            //Toast.makeText(this, data, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        // Try and catch are included to handle any errors due to JSON
                        catch (JSONException e) {
                            // If an error occurs, this prints the error to the log
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                },
                // The final parameter overrides the method onErrorResponse() and passes VolleyError
                //as a parameter
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    // Handles errors that occur due to Volley
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Log.e("Volley", "Error");
                    }
                }
        );
        // Adds the JSON array request "arrayreq" to the request queue
        requestQueue.add(arrayreq);

        user_input.setThreshold(1);
        user_input.setAdapter(adapter);
```

When I try to manually add strings like "India" and "Iran". It works, you can see both of them inside the suggestion drop down but I can't see any of the added data returned back from the server.

This is my autocompletetextview

```
<AutoCompleteTextView
    android:id="@+id/autoCompleteTextView1"
    android:layout_width="350dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/stockLabel"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:completionThreshold="3"
    android:ems="10"
    android:text="@string/symbol" />
```

I have been breaking over my head over this. There isn't any error which I can find on the console. One thing which came to my mind is that, maybe Volley is not responding back in time. 
If I try to print Volley's response in some other widget then it works like charm. Any help is appreciated. TIA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Volley response you are fill data to your arraylist. now do this.

```
 ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
 @Override
 public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
    try {
         JSONObject jsonobj = response.getJSONObject(0);
         data = jsonobj.getString("Name");
         mylist.add(data);
         String[] nameData = new String[mylist.size()];
         nameData = mylist.toArray(nameData );
          adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>  
            (MainActivity.this,android.R.layout.select_dialog_item,mylist);              
           AutoCompleteTextView actv= (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView1);  
           actv.setThreshold(1);//will start working from first character  
           actv.setAdapter(adapter)
           Log.i("here", data);                               
           }                          
          catch (JSONException e) {                            
           e.printStackTrace();

            }
        }
```

Happy coding!!

Comment: I am getting cannot resolve constructor "ArrayAdapter" as the error.

Answer (score 1):

Your request is asynchronous , you have to wait for response before update your UI

Modify your method like this:

```
// Takes the response from the JSON request
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonobj = response.getJSONObject(0);
                            data = jsonobj.getString("Name");
                            mylist.add(data);
                            Log.i("here", data);

                            ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(MainActivity.this,android.R.layout.select_dialog_item, mylist);
                            user_input.setThreshold(1);
                            user_input.setAdapter(adapter);


                        }
                        // Try and catch are included to handle any errors due to JSON
                        catch (JSONException e) {
                            // If an error occurs, this prints the error to the log
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
```